# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. Solution not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

When executing the insert statements, I understand that the last one does not match the number of columns in the table, but I specified the columns I want to insert into, so this should work. But it returns the error message

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT(
        ProjectID       Numeric         NOT NULL,
        ProjectName     Text            NOT NULL,
        Department      Char(35)        NOT NULL,
        MaxHours        Numeric         NOT NULL,
        StartDate       Date            NULL,
        EndDate         Date            NULL,
        CONSTRAINT      PROJECT_PK      PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID),
        CONSTRAINT      PROJ_Depart_FK  FOREIGN KEY(Department)
                                        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)
        );


INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q3 Product Plan', 'Marketing', 135.00, '10-MAY-10', '15-JUN-10');

INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis', 'Finance', 120.00, '05-JUL-10', '05-JUL-10' );

INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q3 Tax Preparation', 'Accounting', 145.00, '10-AUG-10', '15-OCT-10');

INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q4 Product Plan', 'Marketing', 150.00, '10-AUG-10', '15-SEP-10');

INSERT INTO PROJECT (ProjectName,Department,MaxHours,StartDate) VALUES(                                     
    '2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis', 'Finance', 140.00, '05-OCT-10');
```

Comment: The first *four* inserts are the problem, not the last one. This batch can't compile.

Comment: Whats wrong with the first 4?

Comment: Your table has 6 columns, you specify only 5. Always be explicit about your columns; counting on a particular number and order being present is ambiguous and will break on future changes.

Comment: But i dont want to insert anything in to the EndDate column, as it can be null.

Comment: No, you're looking at the last statement again. Look at the *first one*. It should be something like `INSERT INTO PROJECT (ProjectName, Department, MaxHours, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('2010 Q3 Product Plan', 'Marketing', 135.00, '10-MAY-10', '15-JUN-10');` (assuming `ProjectID` is automatically filled, which does not appear to be the case from your definition alone).

Comment: programming__God, were you thinking that the ProjectId should be setup as an IDENTITY column? If it isn't then statements 1-4 are missing the ProjectId and will fail without correlating the column names with the values. You have 5 columns total--you are only correlating them in the last statement.

Comment: Yea as you sent that comment i remembered i need to set up ProjectID as identity. It works now, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include the ProjectID as IDENTITY, in order to auto increment the column

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT(
        ProjectID       int             NOT NULL IDENTITY(1000, 100),
        ProjectName     Text            NOT NULL,
        Department      Char(35)        NOT NULL,
        MaxHours        Numeric         NOT NULL,
        StartDate       Date            NULL,
        EndDate         Date            NULL,
        CONSTRAINT      PROJECT_PK      PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID),
        CONSTRAINT      PROJ_Depart_FK  FOREIGN KEY(Department)
                                        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)

        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a list of columns to insert into (like in your case),  it is equivalent to if you had referenced all the columns; syntactic sugar for when you know  you intend to insert into every column. As such, the fact that you're not specifying an insertion value for all columns, is why you're getting the error.

You can either provide it a value, or an explicit null, or (as is best practice) you should list out the individual columns into which you want to insert

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT 
(
    ProjectName,
    Department, 
    MaxHours,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
)
VALUES('2010 Q3 Product Plan', 'Marketing', 135.00, '10-MAY-10', '15-JUN-10');
```

Comment: Yea but this is not required. I figured out that i needed to have an IDENTITY column for my projectID column. The identity column fixed my issue. you only have to specify the colmuns to insert into when you want to exclude a column or insert different order of columns then the other insert statements